¿porque obtengo error 405 en un metodo inexistente despues de autentificar al usuario al usar laravel echo y angular?
Entonces estoy tratando de implementar un websocket básico con angular y laravel eh llegado a tener varios problemas pero ya casi lo tengo. La situación que no logro resolver es la siguiente. Estoy autentificando al usuario para suscribirse a un canal de presencia cuando probe con canales privados no tuve problemas pero al hacerlo con canales de presencia siempre despues de hacer login obtengo http://localhost:8000/api/v1/login 405 (Method Not Allowed) para mi no tiene sentido por que el login se hace correctamente ademas que en angular en ningun momento envio una peticion de tipo get. Lo curioso es que al recargar la pagina ahora si el usuario que hizo login se suscribe correctamente al canal y funciona todo normal porque podria pasar esto.
Mi login en angular:
 login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .post(`${this.apiUrl}/api/v1/login`, {
        username,
        password,
      })
      .pipe(
        tap((response: any) => {
          sessionStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
          this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(true);
          this.fetchUser();
        }),
        catchError((error) => {
          console.error('Error en el inicio de sesión', error.error);
          return of(error.error);
        })
      );
  }

el servicio para notificaciones con laravel echo

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.setupEcho();
  }
 private setupEcho() {
    (window as any).Pusher = Pusher;
    this.echo = new Echo({
      broadcaster: 'reverb',
      key: 'mi-key',
      wsHost: 'localhost',
      wsPort: 8080,
      wssPort: 8080,
      forceTLS: false,
      enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
      authEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/broadcasting/auth',
      auth: {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('token')}`,
        },
      },
    });
  }

el componente donde se usan el servicio de notificaciones
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.liveNotificationsService.echo
  .join(`notifications.${sessionStorage.getItem('user_id')}`)
      .here((users: any[]) => {
        console.log('Usuarios conectados: ', users);
      })
      .joining((user: any) => {
        console.log('Usuario conectado: ', user);
      })
      .leaving((user: any) => {
        console.log('Usuario desconectado: ', user);
      })
      .listen('.NotificationSent', (e: any) => {
        this.addNotification(e);
      });
  }

destacar que ese error de metodo encontrado supuestamente sale de aca
this.liveNotificationsService.echo.join(notifications.${sessionStorage.getItem('user_id')})
En laravel tengo
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NotificationSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, SerializesModels;

    public $notification;
    public $userId;

    public function __construct($notification, $userId)
    {
        $this->notification = $notification;
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        
        return [new PresenceChannel('notifications.' . $this->userId)];
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'NotificationSent';
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return [
            
        ];
    }
}


junto con su canal

Broadcast::channel('notifications.{userId}', function ($user, $userId) {
    // Permitir solo a los usuarios con id correspondiente acceder al canal
    if (auth()->check()) {
        return ['id' => $user->id, 'name' => $user->name];
    }
    return false;
});

por mas que busco no entiendo que puede estar mal porque tengo que recargar la pagina en angular para que se suscriba correctamente al canal. No se que estoy haciendo mal
